# How do you wire a 3 switch box in a bathroom?

Tags: wiring, bathroom, lighting, switch, exhaust-fan

I'm replacing an old outdated 3 switch unit with a newer one to match the rest of the bathroom. One switch controls a light, one controls the exhaust fan, and the third controls a heating element.  Here's what I know: There are 6 wires coming from the wall. 1 white which is hot, and 2 greys which are hot (but they are spliced together in the box, so really its 1 grey.) Then there are 3 black wires coming from the box as well that are not hot.  To make this even better, the switch is on 2 seperate breakers.  At this point I feel light I have myself a bit backward so any advice is welcome.

On the picture the common wires are wired into the left (1 white, 2 grey), and the 3 black wires are wired into the right.  On the new switch it only has 1 common hook up, then 3 other connectors on the otherside.

[image: Back of old switch; Common wires wire into left (1 white, 2 grey), 3 black wires on the right]

Answer (score 1):

> 1 white which is hot, and 2 greys which are hot...the switch is on 2 seperate breakers.

This means that:

> new switch it only has 1 common hook up, then 3 other connectors on the otherside.

The new switch will NOT work here.

You cannot feed from "2 separate breakers" to "1 common hookup" - you need a different switch that more closely matches the old switches (which look to be 3 separate switches, each with its own connections.)